# intellij IDEA throws NoSuchMethodError when trying to generate WADL from java code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jersey, wadl

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generate(Ljava/util/Set;)Lcom/sun/jersey/server/wadl/ApplicationDescription;
    at com.intellij.ws.rest.GenerateWadlFromJava.createApplication(GenerateWadlFromJava.java:62)
    at com.intellij.ws.rest.GenerateWadlFromJava.main(GenerateWadlFromJava.java:41)
```

**Any idea how to solve this?** It seems IDEA has a jars version dependency issues.

Happens on IDEA version 14.1.6.

Comment: It seems that jersey 1.17 doesn't have the specified method but jersey 1.15 does: https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.15/jersey/com/sun/jersey/server/wadl/WadlBuilder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug in IntelliJ IDEA](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127387).